# Write the dual LP of the primal LP problem

Tags: linear-programming, duality-theorems

I have to find the dual of the lp problem given below
Minimise $$z=-x_1+\frac43 x_2$$
subject to∶ 
$$\begin{array}[t]{l}
2x_1+4x_2\le16\\
-\frac{1}2 x_1-x_2\le4\\
-3x_1+4x_2\ge-24\\
x_1≥0,x_2≤0
\end{array}
$$

Also find the solution to the dual problem without solving it.

Comment: I have found the dual for this. But how to find the solution to the dual without solving it?

Comment: I don't see how you would find the solution to a problem without solving it either...

Comment: actually i have found the solution to the primal problem using graphical method. Is there any way to use that to find the solution for the dual without solving it?

Comment: I am still afraid that when you find the solution to a problem, you have indeed solved it :)

Comment: No according to the question, we do not have to solve the dual. In the first part of this question we have to solve the primal problem via graphical method. After that we are required to find the dual the find the solution for the dual without solving it. I think we have to find the solution using the solution from the graphical method. but i don't know how

Comment: I think the misunderstanding here is with English as opposed to mathematics. It would be more clear to say "find an optimal solution for the dual using results from duality, instead of an algorithm such as simplex."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By evaluating the objective function at each BFS of the primal, we see that $(x_1^\star,x_2^\star)=\left(\frac85,-\frac{24}5\right)$ is an optimal solution, with objective value $-8$. Consider the dual problem:
\begin{align}
\max & \quad 16y_1 +4y_2-24y_3\\
\mathrm{s.t.} &\quad 2y_1-\frac12 y_2-3y_3\geqslant -1\\
&\quad 4y_1 -y_2 +4y_3\leqslant \frac43\\
&\quad y_1,y_2,y_3\geqslant 0
\end{align}
At optimality, $x_1$ and $x_2$ are nonzero, so by complementary slackness, the corresponding constraints in the dual are binding. Also, the constraint in the primal corresponding to the variable $y_1$ in the dual is not binding, so $y_1=0$ at optimality. It follows  that $(y_2, y_3)$ is an optimal basis for the dual, with $y_2^\star = 0$, $y_3^\star = \frac13$, and objective value $8$. This is a feasible solution for the dual with the same objective value as an optimal solution for the primal, and therefore is an optimal solution for the dual.

Answer (score -1):

The prime has infinite many optimal solution as long as x1 belongs to [8/5,8]. However, the dual solution is unique.

Note that the third constraint of the prime problem has to be tight to achieve the optimal value of -8 (dividing it by 3 and you obtain the objective function). Thus, y3 must not equal to 0.
The first and the second constraints of the prime problem are equivalent, and cannot be tight. Thus, y1=y2=0.